# Automatically add site coulmn

Tags: site-column, pages

I have added a metadata site column, and some content types to the default 'Pages' library in my sharepoint site.

How can I have sharepoint automatically add this site column and the content types to the 'Pages' library automatically whenever a site is created?

I am using SharePoint 2010 and C# in Visual Studio 2010

Comment: Add which tools you can use, and handle (C# etc.) and which version of SharePoint you are using to get more attention :)

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is add an Web Provisioned Event Receiver. This will then trigger every time a sub site is created. [Here is an introduction](http://stefan-stanev-sharepoint-blog.blogspot.se/2010/09/webprovisioned-event-receiver-practical.html) from Stefan Stanev.

Then basically locate the site columns and content types from your root site and add them to the Pages library on the new site.

Another approach is to create a [WebTemplate](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vesku/archive/2010/10/14/sharepoint-2010-and-web-templates.aspx) for the new sites to use, in which you add Features that does the [content type bindings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa543598.aspx) and a [Feature Receiver with Feature Activated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231604.aspx) event that binds the site columns that are not part of the Content Types.